# How can I execute SH script in Crontab

Tags: scripts, cron

I have one simple .sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Test1"
touch /home/john/test.txt
echo "Test2"
```

It is executable and available (ugo+x).
If I run this script, it works like I expected.

But if I try to run it in crontab, then I don't get any results.
I can see in log, that job starts and I get *(No MTA installed, discarding output)*.

AFAIK - this message isn't error? It just means that I don't have a mail (or other output channel)?
But why there is no results from script?
BTW - in CRONTAB I use next line:

```
30 * * * * sh file.sh >> /home/john/log.log
```

Any idea?

Comment: How did you edit crontab? `crontab -e`?

Comment: file.sh must be in your home dir. error about MTA mean you won't receive mail from cron job.

Answer (score 4):

If your script is executable, then you don't need to have your crontab running `/bin/sh file.sh`.

Also, `file.sh` probably isn't in the directory crontab runs on. You'll prefer using `/path/to/file.sh`

Redirecting your crontab output, you'll want to catch stderr as well. Having caught both stdout & stderr, I seem to recall crontab no longer complains about its ability to relay output.

```
30 * * * * /path/to/file.sh >> /home/john/log.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, with your suggestions I have found mistake. 
I didn't use full paths in crontab and this was the reason.